# Refreshing view on droplist onchange and keeping state

Tags: javascript, ajax, yii, highcharts

I have a view that contains some user data, a `CListView` with data fetched from a database, representing requests log (IP, key, date/time) and a custom HighCharts widget that draws a chart based on that data.

The `CListView` renders the data without grouping, that is, it's a 1:1 representation of what is saved in the database.

The HighCharts widget *should* render the data grouping it by day, month or year.

I noticed that the `CListView` is capable of re-rendering the entire page without reloading it , doing an AJAX request (which I haven't implemented in my controller).

Is it possible to create a single `dropDownList` widget that will trigger that same AJAX request and make my controller's action respect the selected value?

This is my controller's action:

```
public function actionUser($id)
{
    $usuario = User::model()->with('Contract')->findByPk($id);

    $contract = new CArrayDataProvider($usuario->Contract, array(
            'keyField'=>'idkey'
    ));

    $usage = new CArrayDataProvider($user->Usage, array(
        'keyField'=>'idusage',
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>15
        )
    ));

    $this->render('user',array(
        'user'=>$user,
        'contract'=>$contract,
        'usage'=>$usage
    ));
}
```

And the `dropDownList` widget

```
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('graph', 'gr', array(
    'd'=>'Daily',
    'm'=>'Monthly',
    'y'=>'Yearly'
)); ?>
```

Comment: Use json (by json_encode in php) to communicate your script with javascript ($.getJSON()).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to send an ajax request to your controller to get the data and then return json formatted data to the view. Then re-rendert you highchart with the new data.